# Urban airship jar issue

Tags: java, android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

Hello I decided to use Urban Airship to handle my notification on Android.
But at RunTime this error shows up :

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16575): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9778
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.urbanairship.R$string
        at com.urbanairship.push.NotificationActionButtonGroupFactory.createUrbanAirshipGroups(NotificationActionButtonGroupFactory.java:40)
        at com.urbanairship.push.PushManager.<init>(PushManager.java:198)
        at com.urbanairship.push.PushManager.<init>(PushManager.java:186)
        at com.urbanairship.UAirship.<init>(UAirship.java:107)
        at com.urbanairship.UAirship.executeTakeOff(UAirship.java:302)
        at com.urbanairship.UAirship.access$000(UAirship.java:54)
        at com.urbanairship.UAirship$2.run(UAirship.java:260)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I am trying to use the last Urban airship lib :

> urbanairship-lib-5.0.1.jar

With :

> android-support-v4.jar

My AndroidManifest is following the Documenttation and here is my application class :

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(this);
        options.developmentAppKey = "***";
        options.developmentAppSecret = "***";
        options.productionAppKey = "***";
        options.productionAppSecret = "***";
        options.inProduction = false;
        UAirship.takeOff(this, options);

        //String channelId = UAirship.shared().getPushManager().getChannelId();
        //Log.i(TAG, "My Application Channel ID: " + channelId);
    }
}
```

Comment: AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(getApplicationContext());

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

When you download the latest bundle you will find a folder named urbanairship-lib. Add that folder as a library project to Eclipse, and as a dependency project to your App project. That urbanairship-lib project contains the urban airship-lib-5.0.2.jar as well as the string definitions OUTSIDE the airship-lib-5.0.2.jar. That is why if you only use the airship-lib-5.0.2.jar you get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.urbanairship.R$string. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes thanks I am actually using intelliJ the problem is I added the urban airship library as a library project and now I can either get the      
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.urbanairship.R$string
If I add the jar and the library as dependency of my main project.
But If I The urbanairship-lib project to my main project and the jar as dependency of the urbainairship-lib .. I now get a  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on the urbanairship methods

Comment: You need to add the urbanairship-lib project as a library project to your main app project, just like in th link posted above (http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject), not sure how to do it on IntelliJ. BTW I believe they put the strings outside the JAR in case you need to add languages that they did not think of (see values.xml) etc...

Comment: Yes but when I do that, i've a t java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on each call to any function of the urban airship library ...

Answer (score 1):

You have to ad the urban airship library as a library project 
http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject